# Class constraint must come before any other constraints

Tags: c#, class, generics

I am attempting to create the following class name signature:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : struct, MyBase
```

(I am using struct to constrain to Enums)

I am getting error

```
The class type constraint 'MyBase' must come before any other constraints
```

I understand the message, however, rearranging the code I cannot get past that or some other syntax error. How can I fix that line if at all?

If I have to, I will remove `struct`.

Thank you

Comment: thank you all for your different options due to you guys reading it in different ways.

Comment: Bad news travels slow, you can't constrain a type argument to System.Enum.  History was not kind to enums, they got structurally incompatible by having different sizes for their implementing type.  One optimization too many in the C language, stuck to C# because of interop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you mean `class MyClass<T> : MyBase where T : struct`?

Comment: Thank you. When i tried something similar to this, I was adding a comma `,`. "Light is green, trap is clean."

Answer (score 16):

Constraints are "and-ed" together; *all* the constraints must be satisfied.

Under what circumstances can T be both *a non-nullable value type* and also *be implicitly convertible to the class MyBase via identity, boxing or reference conversion*?

There are no such circumstances, so there is no possible type argument that will satisfy T's constraints. Rather than letting you define a set of constraints that cannot be met, the compiler simply disallows it. You cannot state that you require both the `struct` constraint and a `class type` constraint.

> I am using struct to constrain to Enums

That illustrates my point. Since there are no enums that inherit from `MyBase`, the constraint could not possibly be met.

Can you describe for me what you thought this meant? For example, did you think that it meant "any non-nullable value type **or** any type that is convertible to MyBase"? I am interested to learn why people believe false things about C# so that I can try to improve it.

UPDATE: Ah, I see -- MyBase is intended to be the base class of `MyClass<T>`, not the base class of `T`. In C#, it goes:

```
class [class name] < [generic type parameters] >
    : [base classes and interfaces]
    where [type parameter] : [constraints]
```

You have to put the base classes and interfaces *before* the constraints, otherwise the compiler thinks that they *are* the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `<T>` as two different types. 
`struct` is a value type where as `MyBase` is a class referring to a reference type.
It's not something that is interchangeable.

In this case it would be either:

`public class MyClass<T> where T : struct`

or

`public class MyClass<T> where T : MyBase`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) is so more information regarding generics and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` must be a `struct`, it can't inherit from any other type... Value types don't support inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this, but a quick check of MSDN comes up with this [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T, U> where T : MyBase where U : struct
```

Not sure that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: This would be valid if there were any indication he needed two distinct paraterized types, one independent of the other, but there is no such indication at the moment. It looks as if he simply has competing desires regarding the constraints for a single type parameter.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - That's a valid point, though I read the question differently.  It's not entirely clear (to me) what OP is trying to accomplish, which is why I put the caveat at the end.